# An HTML to image js package which can render all css

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I've seen other questions as well but all of them sugests a paid api or HTML2Canvas.

They are working methods but I don't want to pay for it and HTML2Canvas is not rendering all CSS.

See the difference :-

See [captured by chrome dev tools] :- [chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgFyp.png)

See [captured by html2canvas] :- [html2canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3vEr.jpg)

See [original captured by windows snipping tool] :- [offline screenshot (see background blur and text color difference)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR1QU.jpg)

Is there any tested working method which can render all css and convert html to image with all blurs and color difference

Thank You in advance for Answering

Answer (score 1):

Try Google Chrome in ["headless"](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/headless-chrome/) mode , save page to PDF... and look at the generated/embedded images.

```
outfile="myfile.pdf"
google-chrome --headless --print-to-pdf  https://mypage.io
mv output.pdf $outfile
```

I think option `--screenshot`  is also available.

Comment: I'm looking for converting a Part of HTML such as a div into image